# How do I convert a weakly typed ICollection into an F# List?

Tags: c#, f#

I have an ICollection and need to convert it into a F# List.  If the collection were strongly typed, i.e. ICollection<'T>, it is obvious that I can just write:

```
let myList = List.ofSeq myCollection
```

But how do I do this with a weakly typed collection?

Comment: Do you have a code fragment that does not work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let somecoll = ... // Assuming somecoll is ICollection of something
let whatever = somecoll 
               |> Seq.cast // Getting F# Seq
               |> List.ofSeq // or Array.ofSeq
```

Comment: omg that was frustrating.  Thank you.

If i were to say, do `somecoll.get_enumerator() |> Seq.cast`, would that work too?

Comment: Probably not `Seq.cast` is an alias for `Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` which works on `IEnumerable` interface. `GetEnumerator` returns `IEnumerator`

Comment: @Petr : Seq.cast isn't exactly an alias for Enumerable.Cast ; you can see it's source code [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1053-L1056)

Comment: In my case I needed to add a type annotation -- I had an ICollection from the Hashtable keys. So my code was eventually: `let whatever:seq<string> = somecoll |> Seq.cast`.